# Installing Maven Android SDK Deployer

Tags: java, android, maven

Im trying to install [this](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) maven plugin, but i have several questions which i cant do trial & error because of my slow internet speed :

The documentation said :

```
For the default usage of the deployer install all platforms and add-on apis, ensure that all folder in the platforms folder have names like android-3, android-4 and so on.
```

Do i really need to download ALL of the platforms and extras, even i dont want to use it?

And then, it said :

```
If you find names using the platform version (e.g. 15) in the folder name reinstall that platform from the android tool.
```

This is my `platforms` folder :

[image]

It seems all of my platform's name is using the version, do i really need to re-install ALL of those installed platforms?

Do you have any other way how to make this maven plugin work more easily?

Or do you have any better idea? (different plugin maybe, or anything). Im very new to Maven.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinstall, but make sure you have all the platform levels.When you run the SDK deployer POM, the build will go looking each and every one of the platform level folders and if you have one missing the build will fail. So make sure you have all even if you don't require them. That's why they insist on the folder naming.

This is how missing platform errors look like:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:32 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-29T18:11:29-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/246M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) on project android-10: Properties file not found: $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-10/source.properties -> [Help 1]
```